# Django - 'pop index out of range' error when loop around multiple formset

Tags: python, django

I have three forms that looks like that:

```
class RoomsForm(forms.Form):
  rooms = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)
class PeopleForm(forms.Form):
  adult = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)
  children = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
class ChildrenAgeForm(forms.Form):
  children_age = forms.IntegerField(max_value=10, required=False)
```

Quantity of `PeopleForm` depend on value `rooms` field of `RoomsForm` and quantity of `ChildrenAgeForm` depends on values `children` field of each `PeopleForm`. So i create formsets for `PeopleForm` and `ChildrenAgeForm`, and multiply it using js. Finally i need to create string that looks like this if the value of `rooms`, of example, is `3`:

```
'<Room Adult=2 Children=2>
  <ChildAge>2</ChildAge>
  <ChildAge>1</ChildAge>
</Room>
<Room Adult=1 Children=0>
</Room>
<Room Adult=1 Children=1>
  <ChildAge>3</ChildAge>
</Room>'
```

According to this i create loop script in the `views.py` file:

```
PeopleFormSet = formset_factory(PeopleForm, extra = 1, max_num = 15)
ChildrenAgeFormSet = formset_factory(ChildrenAgeForm, extra = 1, max_num = 20)
rooms_form = RoomsForm(request.POST, prefix='rooms_form')
people_formset = PeopleFormSet(request.POST, prefix='people')
childrenage_formset = ChildrenAgeFormSet(request.POST, prefix='childrenage')
if room_form.is_valid() and people_formset.is_valid() and childrenage_formset.is_valid():
  people = ''
  childrenage_str = []
  for i in range(0, childrenage_formset.total_form_count()):
    childrenage_form = childrenage_formset.forms[i]
    childrenage = str(childrenage_form.cleaned_data['children_age'])
    childrenage_str += childrenage
  for n in range(0, people_formset.total_form_count()):
     childrenage_lst = childrenage_str
     people_form = people_formset.forms[n]
     adults = str(people_form.cleaned_data['adult'])
     children = people_form.cleaned_data['children']
     for i in range(0, children):
       childage_str = ''
       childage = childrenage_lst.pop(i)
       childage_str += '<ChildAge>%s</ChildrenAge>' % childage
       people += '<Room Adults="%s">%s</Room>' % (adults, childage_str)
```

But i got error `pop index out of range`.  Hope you can help me to edit my script in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `pop` you're *removing* elements from the list:

```
>>> mylist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> for i in range(0, len(mylist)): 
...     print(mylist)
...     print(mylist.pop(i))
...
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
4
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
6
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
8
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

So `children`, which you're using the length of, is constant, but `childrenage_lst` is constantly getting shorter and shorter. If you're confident that the two will always start out being the same length, then just access elements in `childrenage_lst` using `[]`:

```
for i in range(0, children):
    print(childrenage_lst[i])
```

That said, because of its initialisation, `childrenage_str = ''` and then `childrenage_lst = childrenage_str`, it looks like `childrenage_lst` is a string, which doesn't have a `pop` method, so I think there's something missing from the code you've posted, to get the TraceBack you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I made mistake in my post `childrenage_str = []`, `childrenage_str` is list not string